# PHP Class Logic

Tags: php, oop, class, abstract-class

My question is rather simple, given:

```
class MyClass{
   function a(){
       echo "F.A ";
   }
   function b(){
       echo "F.B ";
   }
}

$c=new MyClass;
$c->a()->b()->b()->a();
```

So that it will output:

> F.A F.B F.B F.A

What changes to code need to be made for this to work, or should it work as is or even just what this is called.  If I could get whatever this term is called I could research it mysqlf, but I am not quite sure what to Google.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stringing together methods like that is called "chaining."

`return $this;` in each method will enable chainability, since it keeps passing the instance from one method to the other, maintaining the chain.

You have to explicitly do this, since [**PHP functions will return `NULL` by default**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php).

So, you just need 2 more lines.

```
<?php
    class MyClass{
   function a(){
       echo "F.A ";
       return $this; // <== Allows chainability
   }
   function b(){
       echo "F.B ";
       return $this;
   }
}

$c=new MyClass;
$c->a()->b()->b()->a();
?>
```

### **[Live Example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/VucgJ6)**

Take a look at **[this article by John Squibb](http://johnsquibb.com/tutorials/chainable-interface)** for a further exploration of chainability in PHP.

---

You can do all sorts of stuff with chainability. Methods commonly involve arguments. Here's an "argument chain":

```
<?php
   class MyClass{
   private $args = array();
   public function a(){
       $this->args = array_merge($this->args, func_get_args());
       return $this;
   }
   public function b(){
       $this->args = array_merge($this->args, func_get_args());
       return $this;
   }
   public function c(){
       $this->args = array_merge($this->args, func_get_args());
       echo "<pre>";
       print_r($this->args);
       echo "</pre>";       
       return $this;
   }   
}

$c=new MyClass;
$c->a("a")->b("b","c")->b(4, "cat")->a("dog", 5)->c("end")->b("no")->c("ok");

// Output:
//   Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c [3] => 4 [4] => cat 
//           [5] => dog [6] => 5 [7] => end )
//   Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c [3] => 4 [4] => cat 
//           [5] => dog [6] => 5 [7] => end [8] => no [9] => ok )
?>
```

### **[Live Example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/GxQWCd)**

Answer (score 7):

In each function you would have to:

```
  return $this;
```

Comment: Returnin `$this` would allow you to carry on the object line ina chain effect, +1 might as well accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Method chaining is used heavily in domain-specific languages and in particular so called "fluent interfaces", coined by Martin Fowler.  See his DSL book's pre-print online if you want to explore this expressive programming style.   http://martinfowler.com/dslwip/